# Eclipse (Juno) for OSX hangs when I select the Android panel of project properties when more than one SDK is installed

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, freeze

I have set up an Eclipse project for an already-existing phonegap project. It builds and runs fine against Android 4.4.

I tried to add 4.0 as an Android build target through the Android SDK Manager. When I do so, and restart Eclipse, Eclipse hangs when I bring up project properties and click on "Android" to enable the new target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that, for me at least, having more than one SDK target installed at a time causes the hang.

Workaround for me was:

1. Start Eclipse.
2. List item
3. Bring up the Android SDK Manager.
4. Always leave the packages under 'Tools' installed, but remove any
   packages from deploy targets you are not interested in.
5. Add the target you are interested in.
6. Restart Eclipse.